# Word to PHP with custom CSS applied

Tags: php, html

I am trying to convert a word document to PHP but what I want to do is take parts of the word document
and display it with custom HTML CSS.

This is for a T&C page where each heading will be a new section and then have JS + Bootstrap display that section.

If it means I need to add extra tags in the word document it is fine. But would make it easier to maintain if any T&C are changed

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you have any code you can add to show your progress so far? If it is a static page, you might just need to change the content of the page to HTML, rather than using any PHP.

Comment: Hi Squire. Please have a look at this: https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. It might help be useful for your situation.